# Mixing Deferred and deferToThread to run blocking code in separate thread

Tags: python, twisted

In my Python Twisted application I need to receive data from the client, perform some database operations and - depends on data - run some blocking code in separate thread.

So far I have:

```
d = get_user(user_id)

d.addCallback(do_something_with_input_data, input_data)
d.addCallback(run_blocking_code)
d.addCallback(save_data_into_db)
d.addCallback(response_to_client)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def get_user(self, user_id):
    user = yield get_user_from_db(user_id)
    defer.returnValue(user)

def do_something_with_input_data(user, input_data):
    # do smth...
    return results

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run_blocking_code(results)

    threads.deferToThread(run_in_separate_thread, results)
    return results

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def save_data_into_db(results)
    yield save_in_db(results)
    def.returnValue('OK')

def response_to_client(response)
    # send 'OK' to client
```

**Is this a good approach** to call `deferToThread()` in `run_blocking_code()`? If so, how can I make `save_data_into_db()` wait until thread ends?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the general concept is fine. I'd add in some `errbacks`, and you also need to tweak your run_blocking_code function:

```
from twisted.internet import defer, threads

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run_blocking_code(results):

    # the `deferToThread` returns a deferred
    d = threads.deferToThread(run_in_separate_thread, results)

    # let's wait for it here (need a yield for functions decorated with `inlineCallbacks`)
    yield d

    # now return its value to the next function in the callback chain
    defer.returnValue(d.result)
```